# Using Lookup in Linq

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

Need to fetch the first record from Lookup when a condition is satisfied. In below, resId will be key having one or more lists value. In vb, used the below code to fetch the record having resId and record satisfying the below condition. It works perfect.. how can I use the same logic with C#

```
Lookup<Guid, Class> responseLookup;

result = responseLookup(Guid).FirstOrDefault(
                    Function(x) catId.Equals(x.catCode)
```

Tried to convert but was receiving "Method name expected" error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `Guid` in `responseLookup(Guid)` is some `Guid` value, not the type name, the following should work (I suggest using [standard naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/coding-style/coding-conventions) and refrain from using BCL type names as variable names):

```cs
Guid guid = ...;
var result = responseLookup[guid]
    .FirstOrDefault(x => catId.Equals(x.catCode));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
responseLookup[Guid].FirstOrDefault(x => catId.Equals(x.catCode))
```

The `=>` is a lambda-expression. In your case a delegate that excepts a single instance from your list and returns a `bool`.

Comment: Still receiving same error...

Comment: @karthikeyansivakumar what is `catCode`?

Comment: For particular Guid, need to fetch records if the given catId matches with catCode for any list values

Comment: @karthikeyansivakumar you need square brackets for accessing a value from your lookup, not round ones.